ACL permissions not working in SMB mount in ubuntu
SMB mount in Ubuntu is not honoring acl permissions.
Folder created and acl permissions given from windows AD server are working only on windows but not in ubuntu.
Owner of folder and the member of the unix group are able to access but other acl group members are not working.
if the there is a test folder with owner "admin:domain admins"
admin user and domain admins group user are able to access but member of other group assigned permission of folder is not working.

ACLs require support from the underlying filesystem. The Server Message Block protocol doesn't support ACLs.

Is there a way around this where on ubuntu also i can get all permissions that are set from windows machine. for different users and groups in AD. The ubuntu machine is ad joined and wbinfo can list user and groups. On Ubuntu machine i am able to execute id command and command to convert name to uid/gid and uid/gid to SID etc. getcifsacl shows correct permissions but Ubuntu is not checking them for access
